An interesting example of Horizontal and Vertical Lines in TIKZ?
I get a little confused by the case of the following example.
I learn about the meaning of |- and -| in tikz manuals, but the usage like (1,2 -| S) actually raised my curiosity.
the code is as below
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (4,4);
        \coordinate (S) at (2,2);
        \draw[red] (0,0) -- (0,0 -| S);
        \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (0,0 |- S);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (4,4);
        \coordinate (S) at (2,3);
        \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,0 -| S);
        \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (-1,-2 |- S);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (4,4);
        \coordinate (S) at (2,3);
        \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,-| S);
        \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (-1,|- S);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

and I then get the result:

I couln't make sense the behavior with the following docs clearly, just guess the with |- S represented the y-coordinate of S, while the -| S represented the x-coordinate of S, is there some docs I left out?

How can I know what will happen as (x,y -| <point>) or just (x, |- <point>) or even (,y |- <point>) from the docs?Thanks!

note that it is better to use a standard class in examples unless the class matters to the example.

This is very poorly (as in 'not') indexed, but you need to read the documentation of |- in coordinate specifications as opposed to path operations. See page 40 of the manual for initial introduction. Here's the full description from sec 13.3.1 page 144.

However, in almost all cases you should, instead, use the implicit syntax.  Here, you write (<p> |- <q>) or (<q> -| <p>).

I tend to think of this in terms of | specifying the vertical/y coordinate and - the horizontal/x coordinate. (Just as I think of the same syntax when used in a path operation as going up/down-then-across (i.e. vertical-then-horizontal/y-then-x) or across-then-up/down (i.e. horizontal-then-vertical/x-then-y).

For example, (2,1 |- 3,4) and (3,4 -| 2,1) both yield the same as (2,4) (provided the xy-coordinate system has not been modified). The most useful application of the syntax is to draw a line up to some point on a vertical or horizontal line. Here is an example:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (30:1cm) node(p1) {$p_1$}
(75:1cm) node(p2) {$p_2$};
\draw (-0.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node(xline)[right] {$q_1$};
\draw (2,-0.2) -- (2,1.2) node(yline)[above] {$q_2$};
\draw[->] (p1) -- (p1 |- xline);
\draw[->] (p2) -- (p2 |- xline);
\draw[->] (p1) -- (p1 -| yline);
\draw[->] (p2) -- (p2 -| yline);
\end{tikzpicture}

Note that in (<c> |- <d>) the coordinates <c> and <d> are not surrounded by parentheses. If they need to be complicated expressions (like a computation using the $-syntax), you must surround them with braces; parentheses will then be added around them.
As an example, let us specify a point that lies horizontally at the middle of the line from A to B and vertically at the middle of the line from C to D:
% \usetikzlibrary {calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,1)
 {A};
\node (B) at (1,1.5) {B};
\node (C) at (2,0)
 {C};
\node (D) at (2.5,-2) {D};
\draw (A) -- (B) node [midway] {x};
\draw (C) -- (D) node [midway] {x};
\node at ({$(A)!.5!(B)$} -| {$(C)!.5!(D)$}) {X};
\end{tikzpicture}


